# "if" not working properly

Tags: android, arrays, if-statement

hey,
i'm new to android and i have a problem. here is my code:

```
Log.v("Test", "" + lv_arr_id[0]); //displays 0
    if (lv_arr_id[0] == "0") {
      Toast.makeText(longOperationContext, "A", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
      Toast.makeText(longOperationContext, "B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

lv_arr_id[0] has the value "0" and is a string, its external data pulled via json from web. however each time the B toast gets triggered instead of the A toast. the value really is 0, i tested this in the logcat.
any ideas why?
thanks in advance

Comment: if works fine :) but '=='-comparing is not the best in your case :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

== compares the object and not the String contents. Use .equals("0") instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that **if** is not working properly.

In Java, you can't use `==` to compare objects of `java.lang.String` class. You need to use `equals` method.

Something like:

```
if (lv_arr[0].equals("0")) {
    // 
} else {

}
```